# Materialize : How to remove margin between divs

Tags: html, css, materialize

While using `col` there is some extra margin between `divs. How to reduce this extra margin without using any inline css:

**It looks like this:** [image: Result]

How I want it:[image: After inlining]

**My Code :**

```css
.item-card{
    position: relative;


}
.card-lable{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.max-width{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col m10 offset-m1">
    <div class="col m4 item-card" >
      <img class="max-width" src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg">
      <div class="card-lable"><h4>owl</h4></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m4 item-card" >
        <img class="max-width" src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg">
        <div class="card-lable"><h4>owl</h4></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.offset-m1,.item-card{padding-left:0!important;}`

```css
.item-card{
    position: relative;
}
.card-lable{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.max-width{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.offset-m1,.item-card{
padding-left:0!important;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col m10 offset-m1">
    <div class="col m4 item-card" >
      <img class="max-width" src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg">
      <div class="card-lable"><h4>owl</h4></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m4 item-card" >
        <img class="max-width" src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg">
        <div class="card-lable"><h4>owl</h4></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it worked but I just want to know if I added this to col it will override the default property of col, does it will affect all other div in future?

Comment: I changed the code to the  `.offset-m1,.item-card{padding-left:0!important;}` to only affect this part

Comment: By reducing the value of `margin-left:8.3333333333%` in `.offset-m1` to the desired place